# Writing a Python defaultdict to Mongo fails

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I can't seem to write a `defaultdict` to MongoDB using PyMongo. I get an `_id` back, but the document isn't written.

```
>>> coll
Collection(Database(Connection('localhost', 27017), u'db_name'), u'coll_name')
>>> doc
{'field1': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {...}), 'field2': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {...})}
>>> obj_id = coll.insert(doc)
>>> obj_id
ObjectId('50cdc4df15b6f6dc3f496af7')
>>> coll.find_one()  # nothing...
>>> [x for x in coll.find({'_id': '50cdc4df15b6f6dc3f496af7'})]
[]
```

What's going on here? How can I debug this failed write?

**EDIT**:

Upon switching my connection to `safe=True` I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "populate_mongo.py", line 36, in <module>
    oid = coll.insert(series)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 359, in insert
    continue_on_error, self.__uuid_subtype), safe)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 852, in _send_message
    rv = self.__check_response_to_last_error(response)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 795, in __check_response_to_last_error
    raise OperationFailure(details["err"], details["code"])
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: too many namespaces/collections
```

So this seems like Mongo can't hold my data, and irrelevant to the collection being a `defaultdict`.

Comment: So you can't insert anything into your `coll`? Not even `{'test': 1}` ?

Comment: You can cast a `defaultdict` to a regular `dict` with ease: `{k, dict(v) for k, v in doc.iteritems()}`.

Comment: @JonClements, that's correct, as you can see in my edit I'm getting a `too many collections` error.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Why so eloborate? Just `dict(default_dict)` :)

Comment: @Yuval can't help then - what's `coll.count()` equal? Also, for the record, inserting a `defaultdict` works fine - just tried it...

Comment: @JonClements: because `doc` is a dictionary *containing* `defaultdict` instances. It is not in and of itself a `defaultdict`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so it is, \*whistles\* innocently :)